# Django: newbie question on Model managers

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django and I'd like to understand how to use managers. I've read the documentation but need a little help putting it into practice.

I've got models as follows:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
class PlaceRef(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    value = models.FloatField()
    units = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

If I had a particular `Place`, should I use a Manager to add up the value of all the `PlaceRefs` associated with it? (assuming for the sake of simplicity that all the units are the same...)

```
place = Place.objects.get(id=id)
value = PlaceRef.objects... # what to do here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a new manager here. There's already an automatic manager that deals with the relationship between Place and PlaceRef - it's accessed via `place.placeref_set`.

But to add up the values, you need to use [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) - specifically, the `aggregate` method.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
value = place.placeref_set.aggregate(Sum('value'))
```

Now `value` is a dictionary with a single value containing the sum of all the values in the associated PlaceRefs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this as an attribute of place

```
class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    @property
    def placeref_total(self):
      do your calculation here as suggested in Daniel's answer
      value = self.placeref_set.aggregate(Sum('value'))
      return value
```

then you can refer to it in your code:

```
  myplace = Place.objects.get(id=x)
  myplace.placeref_total
```

If you don't use the @property decorator, then refer to it as:
      myplace.placeref_total()